# Filling information when changing dropdown in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I do a query on a table and obtain 25-30 results.

```
$items = item::all();
```

And then give it to the blade:

```
return view("myview",compact'items');
```

I display those results on my blade like this:

```
@foreach($items as $item)
<select onchange="changeTextInputs()">
<option value="{{item->id}}">{{$item->name}}<input type="hidden" value={{item->color}}>
<input type="hidden" value={{item->shape}}>
<input type="hidden" value={{item->color}}>
...
</option>
@endforeach
<input type ="text" value="" id="item_color">
<input type ="text" value="" id="item_shape">
...
```

When changing the select, my javascript fills the inputs with the information of each item - as intended. Everything works just fine.

I honestly don't like to put the hidden inputs in the selects. Anyone knows other way to do this on Laravel?

Comment: why you are maintaining hidden fields..

Comment: You could have those values in Javascript as variables, and on submiting form just pass those variables to your Controller with ajax. On change you call your function `changeTextInputs()` which don't update hidden field, instead updates your Javascript variables.

Comment: @Sona I need to pass the information from Blade to HTML so Javascript can use it to fill the text inputs whenever I change the dropdowns.

Comment: while doing onchnage you need to add the value to fields??

Comment: @Sona I don't need to "add" them just change the values to whichever has been selected, which are in the hidden inputs.

Comment: How do you select them while they are hidden?

Comment: The best way is you just pass the item->id as selected value and find the detail in controller where you are posting the form using this id. or try to save the whole object in option value(not sure about it)

Comment: while onchanging use ajax function to get the selected id values from controller and append to the fields

Comment: @KuKeC I will just do this. I will just use AJAX. Still, I though Laravel already had some sort of function for this.

Comment: concat all values with special charcters like this <option value="{{item->id .^^^. item->color .'^^^'}}">{{$item->name}}  later use split or explode depends upon language

Comment: @prgrm Glad to help you